# Gluon Afterburner getPresenter() returns only NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: gluon, nosuchelementexception

I generate a simple app from Gluon Start with Glisten Afterburner (v2.1.0). This generates three classes of which two are Main and AppViewManager using glisten.afterburner AppView and AppViewRegistry. I add an additional View to the generated code ("Other") and I add methods to AppViewManager to get the Presenter associated with a View.

The generated Main class looks like the following to which I have added the static calls to get Presenters: getMainPresenter() and getOtherPresenter():

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private final AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize(this::postInit);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        AppViewManager.registerViewsAndDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        appManager.start(stage);
    }

    private void postInit(Scene scene) {
    :
       // Get Main Presenter
       AppViewManager.getMainPresenter();
       // Get Other Presenter
       AppViewManager.getOtherPresenter();
    }
    :
}
```

AppViewManager looks like the following where I added the additional View ("Other") and added methods to get Presenters associated with Views. In registering Views, I added some output to see what is going on:

```
public class AppViewManager {
    private static final AppViewRegistry REGISTRY = new AppViewRegistry();

    public static final AppView MAIN_VIEW = view("Home", MainPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.HOME, SHOW_IN_DRAWER, HOME_VIEW, SKIP_VIEW_STACK);
    public static final AppView OTHER_VIEW = view("Other", OtherPresenter.class, MaterialDesignIcon.NOTE, SHOW_IN_DRAWER, SKIP_VIEW_STACK);

    private static AppView view(String title, Class<?> presenterClass, MaterialDesignIcon menuIcon, AppView.Flag... flags ) {
        return REGISTRY.createView(name(presenterClass), title, presenterClass, menuIcon, flags);
    }

    private static String name(Class<?> presenterClass) {
        return presenterClass.getSimpleName().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).replace("PRESENTER", "");
    }

    public static void registerViewsAndDrawer()
    {
        for (AppView view : REGISTRY.getViews())
        {
            // What's in the REGISTRY?
            System.out.println("==> View: " +view.getId()+ ", Presenter: " +view.getPresenterClass().getCanonicalName());
            // Not sure what the following does, the javadoc is blank!
            view.registerView();
        }
    :
    }
    
    /**
     * Get MainPresenter.
     * See: .../AppViewRegistry.html#getPresenter(com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.afterburner.AppView)
     */
    public static void getMainPresenter()
    {
        MainPresenter mp = (MainPresenter)MAIN_VIEW.getPresenter().get();
        System.out.println("..Presenter..> " +mp.toString());
    }
    
    public static void getOtherPresenter()
    {
        OtherPresenter op = (OtherPresenter)OTHER_VIEW.getPresenter().get();
        System.out.println("..OtherPresenter..> " +op.toString());
    }
}
```

OtherPresenter is a simple declaration:

```
public class OtherPresenter {
    public void initialize() {}
}
```

The OtherPresenter FXML is:

```
<View fx:id="other" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.runtheworld.sample.OtherPresenter">
    <center>
        <VBox styleClass="box">
            <children>
                <Label text="Other!" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</View>
```

What's in the REGISTRY output is as expected (except I would have expected 'HOME_VIEW' rather than 'home'):

```
==> View: home, Presenter: com.runtheworld.sample.MainPresenter
==> View: OTHER_VIEW, Presenter: com.runtheworld.sample.OtherPresenter
```

But no matter where I make the getOtherPresenter() call, it returns: "Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present". The getMainPresenter() call, however, works.  In fact, the app functions, showing OtherPresenter (displaying "Other!") but still throwing "No value".

Why does Main work but not Other, is there some setup/init I have missed?

Here's all the output:

```
==> View: home, Presenter: com.runtheworld.sample.MainPresenter
==> View: OTHER_VIEW, Presenter: com.runtheworld.sample.OtherPresenter
Apr 03, 2022 11:24:16 AM com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform <clinit>
INFO: [Gluon Attach] System Property javafx.platform is not defined. Platform will be set to Platform.DESKTOP
..MainPresenter..> com.runtheworld.sample.MainPresenter@686bbb76
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:143)
    at com.runtheworld.sample.AppViewManager.getOtherPresenter(AppViewManager.java:54)
    at com.runtheworld.sample.Main.postInit(Main.java:41)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.continueInit(AppManager.java:328)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.start(AppManager.java:288)
    at com.runtheworld.sample.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

EDIT:
I decided to eschew afterburner and simply built a View as follows:

```
public class OtherView {
    public static final String OTHER_VIEW = "OTHER_VIEW";
    
    public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<View,Presenter>> getViewController() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader f = new FXMLLoader(OtherView.class.getResource("/path/to/other.fxml"), ResourceBundle.getBundle("path.to.other"));
            View view = f.load();
            
            OtherPresenter controller = f.getController();
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(OTHER_VIEW,new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(view,controller));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The View and Controller are defined in the FXML and this ties the View name to the View and its associated Controller. getViewController() is called from Main.init().

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? In any case, `getPresenter()` returns an `Optional`, and `get()` should be called only via `ifPresent()`, like: `OTHER_VIEW.getPresenter().ifPresentOrElse(op -> System.out.println("..Presenter..> " + op), () -> System.out.println("no OtherPresenter yet"));`. In `postInit`, only the main view has been loaded, so it makes sense that the second view doesn't return the presenter yet, which happens when you load that view.

Comment: Added output plus stacktrace.  I shall try to access Other in postInit, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is regular FXML after all, you don’t get the controller unless you load it, which is the case for the main/home view. For other views you’ll need to inject them if you want to access them if they are not loaded.

Comment: If I add in something like to postInit(): AppViewRegistry avr = AppViewManager.getRegistry();
        avr.getView("OTHER_VIEW").get().switchView(); this works, no stacktrace.  Does switchView() then load the Controller?

Comment: Yes, that’s precisely the way to load and switch between views. I take that you have checked the Gluon samples and their detailed tutorials? For instance: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/notes#quick-instructions

Comment: I did look at that and had something similar but not in the detail...  I'll go back and try again and post back either way.  Thanks.